# Android WebView not loading Javascript on error

Tags: android, webview

I have a Android WebView loading a page with Javascript(AngularJS) code.  The page with Javascript code does not display at all except the circular progress bar is showing.  On Logcat I see this error:

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(117)] "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Is there a way to handle this error and still get the page to load?  It's working on desktop Chrome browser where the page is loading fine.

Currently, I have done the following on my webView instance:

```
   webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(webChromeClient);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        Log.i(getClass().toString(), "loading link in self");
        return true;
    }

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.i(getClass().toString(), " page finished");
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
        if(url.startsWith("http://example.org/pdflinks")) {
            Log.i(getClass().toString(), "loading in Google PDF viewer url: " + url);
            loadPdfItem(url);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
        Log.e(getClass().toString(), "error: " + error);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedHttpError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse) {
        Log.e(getClass().toString(), "received http error: " + errorResponse);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + errorResponse, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //super.onReceivedHttpError(view, request, errorResponse);
    }
}

class MyWebChromClient extends WebChromeClient {
    @Override
    public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage consoleMessage) {
        Log.i(getClass().toString(), "console.message: " + consoleMessage.message());
        return false;
        //return super.onConsoleMessage(consoleMessage);
    }

}
```

thanks for any insight.

Comment: I'm running into this issue as well, did you resolve it?  I'm surprised there aren't more responses to this.